# anyway to make menu items small...?

Tags: android

i was wondering if there is anyway `to decrease the size of menu items displayed` from either xml or through coding...?

another question is that can i draw the tabwidget on the bottom of the screen. i mean i want them on the bottom can i do that...?

another question is that is there any `two column list view` in android. now i know that there is a `list view with two item` but they are following each other.one is below the other but is there any `listview` that has columns just like in a table...?

Comment: Don't place tab widgets on the bottom. Its super easy to do but Android design guidelines tell not to...

Comment: This looks like three individual questions.

Comment: so whats the problem if i ask three individual question once...?

Comment: u can answer just one of them...

Comment: @kashifmehmood It's not helpful for future visitors with similar problems because each individual issue is hard to find. Questions on SO should always be helpful to others apart from the person asking. If that's not the case, questions usually get closed as "too localized". The idea of SO is basically to build a library with problem solutions, not to help just one person at a time. Also you can't accept all solutions if they are split across answers. So please split these questions into seperate posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your third question, you can find good tutorial here :

```
http://www.technotalkative.com/android-multi-column-listview/
```

To answer your second question, you can do as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
<TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```